# List all types implementing an interface in Go

Tags: go, goland, go-interface, go-guru

I'm new to Go, and I'd like to know if there's a way in Goland or w/ a CLI tool to list all the types that implement a given interface.

I found a tool called [`guru`](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1_Y9xCEMj5S-7rv2ooHpZNH15JgRT5iM742gJkw5LtmQ/edit) that can list all interfaces implemented by a given type, but I haven't been able to make it work in CLI.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `Navigate | Declaration` or `Navigate | Implementation(s)` on any type/interface and you'll see a list of interfaces implemented by a type or of types implementing an interface.

You can also use the green buttons on the IDE left side next to their type definitions to perform the same actions.